# plotly displaying too many digits on y axis

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I have noisy data that bounces around between 0 and 1. When the values are around 0 the y axis displays reasonable y-labels for the y axis. However when the values are around 1, the yaxis labels are too long as too many digits are showing and getting cut off by other things on the page. I created a simple code pen that demonstrates the problem here:

https://codepen.io/mmakrzem/pen/ZEbBENK

```
const plotEl = document.getElementById('myDiv');

const numLines = 1;
const numDataPoints = 8;

const x = Array.from( { length: numDataPoints }, ( _, i ) => i );

function getY( offset, num ) {
  return Array.from( { length: num }, ( _, i ) => offset + Math.random() * 1e-10 );
}

const data = [ 
  {
    x,
    y: getY( 0, numDataPoints ),
    xaxis: "x",
    yaxis: "y",
  }
];

const layout = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    showlegend: true,
}

Plotly.newPlot(plotEl, data, layout)

let t = numDataPoints;
const iHandle = setInterval( () => {
    t += 1;
    
  const offset = Math.floor( t / numDataPoints ) % 2;
  
    const update = {
        x: [[t]],
        y: [getY( offset, 1 )]
    };  
    Plotly.extendTraces( plotEl, update, [ 0 ], 4 );
    
    if( t > 90 ) {
        clearInterval( iHandle );
    }
}, 1000 );
```

How can the y axis labels be fixed so they don't show so many digits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickformat.

I added tickformat to yaxis. This code should only be displayed up to three digits below the decimal point.

Plotly's tickformat follows the d3.js method.

For more information on tickformat, see this link.
[d3.js tickformat](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/v3.0.0/README.md#axis_tickFormat)

```
const layout = {
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    showlegend: true,
    yaxis: {
      tickformat: '.3f',
    },
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code pen: https://codepen.io/mmakrzem/pen/ZEbBENK but there is still a problem when the numbers are large... note now I'm fluctuating around 10M but the y axis labels are being cut off